# Compiled and installed compat wireless. How do i remove it

Tags: wireless, compat-wireless

I tried to compile and install manually a new version of compat wireless on my ubuntu 12.10, because i had a bit wifi problems. The problems aren't gone but now my internal wifi card (atheros ar9485) doesen't show (tried modprobe ath9k, no success), and i want to get back to like things was before. Used checkinstall and have tried `dpkg -r compat-wireless` but when i reeboot after the uninstall then i get no visible  wifi connections (i have an usb dongle which uses rt2800 driver too which doesent show).

Comment: How *exactly* did you install it? Can you edit your answer to provided the specific, full commands? (You said you used `checkinstall` but can you provide more details please?)

Comment: After unpacking the bz2 i did this:
`./scripts/driver-select rt2800`
`make`
`sudo checkinstall`

Clicked enter through the checkinstall except the last one where it said "yes could be a good idea". Was something about exclude something.

Answer (score 0):

This problem sometimes happens because installing the new package replaces an old (or otherwise different) version, and uninstalling the new one leaves you without either.

Perhaps a previous version of `compat-wireless` was installed *before* you installed with `checkinstall`. If so, you should reinstall that.  You can check whether or not this was the case by looking at `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: I did an `apt-get upgrade` so it has no entrie before that. I haven't installed any network related software, so what do ubuntu 12.10 uses as default?

Comment: @user1937237 Running `apt-get upgrade` doesn't reset `dpkg.log`. You can look farther back in the files whose names start with `dpkg.log` followed by a number, but it is probably not necessary--you wouldn't be looking for an entry documenting the older version's *installation*, but rather its *removal*. (Ubuntu 12.10 does not have any package *called* `compat-wireless`, though, so if you used an official Ubuntu ISO to install and didn't customize the system or install software from your computer's manufacturer, it's unlikely installing `compat-wireless` with `checkinstall` replaced it.)

Comment: I may add i used --purge on the removal first time. Maybe it has some impact.

Comment: @user1937237 `--purge` doesn't affect what is logged. It just causes systemwide configuration files belonging to packages being removed, to be removed too. Feel free to post your log file(s) at http://paste.ubuntu.com and update your question with a link, if you wish.